# Upgrade from 8.1 to 9.0 origin not allowed

Tags: grafana

HOpe that someone help me. I have search and search and try several solutions but I still get this error of Origin not allowed on Grafana. I understand this is related with the proxy reverse but I think its correct

My httpd.conf with proxy reverse:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /..

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias 11.11.11.11
        ServerAlias example01.*
        
        DocumentRoot /app/...
        
        <Location "/grafana">
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
            
        </Location>
        
        
        ErrorLog logs/...
        CustomLog logs/...
        
</VirtualHost>
```

is it something missing or the problem could be in another place?

Thanks in davance.

Comment: Hi Alexandre,
I'm having the same issue upgrading to 9.1.6
Have you found a fix for this?

Comment: @RobertoJobet I didn't find any solution. I rollback the upgrade